# why do we put network calls inside the react useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs

the question has troubled me for a long time.

why do we have to put api calls inside useEffect hook, which means we get data after the dom is mounted.

why can't we call the apis and mount the dom at the same time? why do we have to wait until the dom is mounted?

Comment: Well, setting aside where we put the code for a sec, do you agree that it takes time for a network call to complete?

Comment: yes the network calls takes time

Comment: Nothing's stopping you making a network request outside of the component lifecycle. The challenge then comes in delaying rendering until data is available. React provides the [<Suspense>](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense) component for just such a scenario but it's not trivial to implement. The typical effect hook approach is a lot easier and makes sense if you consider async data loading a side-effect (hence the hook name)

Comment: K, then the only way we'd be able to use the data in the first render is if react could block rendering until we have it. They actually do that in server components, but on the client side blocking the render is a no go. So whether we do the effect before the render or after, we're still not going to have the data in time. In which case, what's the benefit of doing it before the render? The benefit of effects running after is that any effects that need to interact with the dom, can (doesn't matter for fetching data, but other effects i mean)

Comment: thank you very much! your explaination shed light on my confusion. thanks for your patience again.

Answer (score -2):

1.It doesn't say that it must be called in useEffect, but it can also be called in useMemo, but the official recommendation is generally in useEffect, or it is suitable for most scenarios

2.Because network requests take time, it is not impossible to render the dom if you wait for network data to arrive, but the user's white screen time will be longer. You can even implement your own react component that gets the data and then renders the dom

3.Different components may match different api interfaces, and different interfaces have different speeds, so it is not very cost-effective to wait for interfaces to render components

4.If you have to want this effect, you can use React's render method after using the api interface

In addition, I also think that the code style of useEffect method is really ugly and useRef, no way who calls react popular?